# Apigee - Select multiple values from a key value map

Tags: apigee

I have a number of key value pairs in a key value map as I am trying to map an internal id to an external one. My API is given a list of ids to map and I iterate through them calling the keyvalue map API for each one using javascript. This works, but I'd rather call the API once and get all the corresponding entries in one go.

It would be even better if I could do this using a KeyValueMap policy.

Is this possible?

Comment: Whoops, I misread your question -- I've deleted my answer as it doesn't apply.

Comment: Unfortunately the KeyValueMapOperations policy doesn't allow you to provide a list of keys. You can call the API using `GET https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{org}/e/{env}/keyvaluemaps/{kvmName}` and get the entire KVM if it is not too big. Then, in Javascript, you should be able to use `JSON.parse` to convert the payload to a JavaScript object and loop through the entry array, but only if the number of entries in the KVM is reasonable. However, it is generally not recommended to use Apigee management API calls from within an Apigee proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API that will take a list of keys for a key value map  and return the corresponding values.